# causes of Python IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, permission-denied, ioerror

When attempting to write a file, I can get this same error when any of following conditions applies:

1. The file exists and is marked read-only.
2. I don't have write permission for the folder and therefore cannot create a
   file.
3. The file is already open in another process.

Is there any way to separate out the above three causes?  If not, then I would
say that this is an extraordinarily poor design.

Comment: Perhaps check for file permissions and narrow down the possible cases.

Answer (score 0):

You get the same `Exception` as your base problem is "You can't do this" but the details are contained in the exception instance, (or in a string on older pythons), so if you handle the problem as:

```
try:
    outfile = open('somename.txt', 'w')
except IOError, e:
    print "Not allowed", e
```

You will get a lot more information. (N.B. if you are running python 3 you will need to add brackets to the print above).

This is actually incredibly good design - your basic problem is that there is a problem - and you can find out more if you care to - and you can handle a given class of problem in a generalised manner.

Comment: Here's my code:

    try:
       OUT= open('test.txt', 'w')
       OUT.write('junk')
       OUT.close()
    except IOError as ex:
       print("Not allowed because %s." % ex)

If the file test.txt is marked as read-only, I get the following error message:

    Not allowed because [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.txt'.

If test.txt is locked because I've opened it in an application such as Microsoft Word, I get exactly the same error message.  So, I reiterate my position that this is a poor design.

Comment: I'm hoping that someone else might be able to add to this discussion.

Comment: @PhillipM.Feldman the problem there is that the Operating System only informs applications "Permission Denied" not why permission is denied - you will find the same thing in just about all programming languages not just python - other than a few which just fail silently either simply crashing or worse letting you "write" to a non-existent file and loose your work or in the case of MS Office let you open the file, make changes and then moan when you try to save it.

Comment: Long article on this sort of thing on Windows at http://www.online-tech-tips.com/software-reviews/how-to-fix-access-is-denied-file-may-be-in-use-or-sharing-violation-errors-in-windows/