# Python does not have permission to open .txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Disclaimer This question might be a duplicate of a question I could not find by searching.

I am trying to open a .txt file I downloaded. I used:

```
with open("spam.txt", "a+") as ef:
    #other code that works
```

and I am getting`IOError [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'spam.txt'`

Is there something I did wrong or do I have to open the file a different way?

Edit: I checked and I do have all the read, write, and execute permissions for the file and I can open it on Notepad. I am using Windows as my OS.

Comment: Check your file permission , maybe its not readable for you

Comment: @Arman I checked that, it says I have all the permissions for the file

Comment: Maybe you are running script as another user?

Comment: Duplicate of [causes of Python IOError: Errno 13 Permission denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060547/causes-of-python-ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied)?

Comment: Try open it with `try`

Comment: This may be incredibly trivial, but are you sure the file isn't opened on your machine somewhere already?

Comment: @Arman Still can't open the file

Comment: @N.Wouda I checked that too and it is not open anywhere

Comment: when open it with `try Except` you can have a good error message, maybe you can find where you should correct

Comment: rest assured, if the system says you don't have permission to open a file, you don't have permission to open the file. The best explanation are that you're not opening the file you think you are, or  you are misinterpreting what permissions the file actually has. If you give a fully qualified, absolute path to the file, do you still get the same error?

Comment: @BryanOakley The system says I have permissions, Python says I don't/it doesn't.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann: python is doing nothing but asking the operating system. Python doesn't have its own notion of permissions.

Comment: Well, I figured out the problem. Komodo Edit has some issue with permissions. It runs fine when I run it using a Python window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I got the problem fixed. It turned out that Komodo Edit 9.3 needs to be in Admin Mode in order to do anything with files now.

The way to get past it is to run Komodo Edit as Admin or run it from a Python window.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is your code. Are you on a linux environment?  If so, check to see if the file has read permissions.

The code works just fine.

```
with open("white-list.txt","a+") as ef:
    print ef
<open file 'white-list.txt', mode 'a+' at 0x10206a6f0>
```

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Please don't ask questions in answers. Try to ask questions in comments first and then answer the question with this information.